# Ensure data deserialization / serialization

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have 3 `ObservableCollections` in my `ViewModel` and one `Class` which I load when you run an app.
To ensure `ObservableCollections` are deserialized I just got.

```
if(SomeCollection.Count == 0)
   ThisCollection = await deserializationMethod<ObservableColletion<T>>(filename);
```

If there is no file, `deserializationMethod` will create new object with

```
return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

That works fine - no problem with that.

And for class I have

```
if(ClassObject.Loaded != true)
   ThisObject = await deserializationMethod<T>(filename);
```

I added a property - if file is deserialized then it's true.
It looks like it works but it is NOT. It happens very rarely but sometimes file is not deserialized and when you use an app this file is overwritten so every data are destroyed. I cannot find what is causing the problem. It is that you just run an app and it happens - like once per 100 runs.

How to be very sure that if file exist then it will be deserialized for sure?
Or maybe I should make `List` of these `ObservableCollections` + `Class` and serialize it to one file? Is there any good practice with that?

**EDIT:**

I used `SemaphoreSlim` to ensure that everything is used as it supposed to, but today it happened again.

The thing is it happens when app is started and nothing else is even tapped. There is no way that something is writing at this moment. It looks like data is not deserialized or is not reading the file that exist. Because every changes are written with closing an app then everything is gone.
Any other ideas what it might be or how to be sure that data are deserialized?

**EDIT FINAL - reproduced problem:**

I finally reproduced what is going on. So I've removed edits with code that wasn't necessary here.

I have `BackPressed` event to handle when user is going back or want to exit an app (if on `MainPage`).
This part of code apparently was causing the problem. What is going on exactly.
First thing is that problem isn't possible to be reproduced using emulator.
My `BackPressed` method contained await with serializing method that saved the data that were later gone (so as Ondrej Svejdar has written it was writing before reading). BUT I started to test it and there is strange behaviour and I still have some questions about it.

How it happens.

When I started an app (by accident e.g.) and loading screen occurs I start to tap back button few times -> app isn't running it is closing ASAP and I can't even see a UI (sometimes I am able to see AppBar for a moment). Then when I try to open app again (doesn't matter if immediately or later) it is "resuming" and after this exact moment my data are gone. But not all of the data. Only the last one saved with await within `BackPressed` method. Only this one. I tried to save One, Two and Three `ObservableCollections` with and without this Class and ALWAYS the last one was saved "empty". After this awaits I got Application.Current.Exit() method that might cause this, but I'm not sure if this should matter when serializing method is *Task* and only the last one is wrongly serialized.

When I remove this awaits from BackPressed method I can't reproduce this issue so this is it.

Questions I still have are: Is this behavior expected? Is there better method to close an app and ensure serializing data or I just should save it during using an app not while exiting it?

Comment: Are you serializing the file somewhere as well ? It seems like a threading issue - read after write hazard. File operation - both read/write should be in critical section (only one thread allowed). In C# that means that both read and write should be guarded by the lock(_mySyncRoot) {} and the _mySyncRoot should be the same object for both read and write.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't come up with this looking for the solution and it sounds like this is it. I will implement this later today and after few weeks of testing I'll post if it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested how to do it properly I was thinking about it and come up with few conclusions.
Keep in mind that this are my suggestions and there might be better approach.

While handling *BackPressedButton* event (the hardware one) I had an implementation of *GoBack* to previous page (if not on *MainPage*) or leave an app if on MainPage.
I was closing an app using *Application.Current.Exit()* and that wasn't causing problems (because I was saving very small files) until I started doing strange things (read *"EDIT FINAL - reproduced problem:"* of the question for more details). 
Thing was the file wasn't saved because an app was closed before writing has finished. Solution is actually very simple. To my *Save* method which is a *Task* it just should return *true* value when writing is finished and this value should be checked while closing an app.

```
bool saved = await saveDataAsync<T>(whichData, dataFileName)
     if(saved)
         Application.Current.Exit();
```

and serializing method looks like this (I'm using semaphoreSlim in case there is possibility to two methods trying to reach the same file)

```
    public async Task<bool> saveDataAsync<T>(T whichData, string dataFileName)
    {
        var Serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        await mySemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(dataFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
            {
                Serializer.WriteObject(stream, whichData);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            mySemaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
        return true;
    }
```